# Getting NaNs from nested LME

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme

Having some issues with a subset of my data (subset still has 600 values). For the experiment, I have two time points, nested within each are three treatments (TT), with 5 replicate cultures nested within them (A through E). Within each of these cultures are 20 values for individual organisms. For this subset I want to look at difference between treatments and differences between timepoints within the same treatment.

I am using R 3.1.2 and nlme package

My code is as follows:

```
model4a <-lme(Velocity~WeekTT, random=~1|Week/TT/Culture, method = "REML", data=body2, weights = varIdent(form=~1|WeekCulture), control=lmeControl(opt="optim"))
```

STR is below:

```
    data.frame':   600 obs. of  4 variables:
     $ Culture  : Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 
     $ Treatment: Factor w/ 3 levels "T20","T25","T25F": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 
     $ Week     : num  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
     $ Velocity : num  259 279 265 275 256 ...
```

Here is a screengrab of the results I get and the errors at the bottom (Working on posting some reproducible data but figured it might be a simple code error).

[image]

I've been crunching different models for the past 3 week and I think it's an easy question just my brain is frazzled and i'm overthinking it.

Comment: Please include sample input data to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

If `WeekTT` is the week-by-treatment interaction, then you've included it twice in your model, once as a fixed effect and once as a random effect, because the random effects grouping structure `Week/TT/Culture` expands to `Week + Week:TT + Week:TT:Culture`, so it's not surprising that these fixed effect parameters will be unidentifiable.  Perhaps, if you want to keep the fixed effect, include only the three-way interaction as the random effect.

```
model4a <-lme(Velocity~WeekTT, 
               random=~1|Week:TT:Culture, 
      method = "REML", data=body2, 
    weights = varIdent(form=~1|WeekCulture), 
    control=lmeControl(opt="optim"))
```

Depending on what the `weights` statement is doing (does `WeekCulture` represent the three-way interaction?  Will a data transformation take care of the heteroscedasticity?), you might be able to just aggregate the lowest level (i.e. compute the mean of each `Week:TT:Culture` combination), as would be suggested by [Murtaugh (2007)](http://www.esajournals.org/doi/abs/10.1890/0012-9658%282007%2988%5B56%3ASACIED%5D2.0.CO%3B2) "Simplicity and complexity in ecological data analysis".  Then you wouldn't need a mixed model at all ...